# How to Select Element That Does Not have parent Class in "pure" JS?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

How can i include all `.article-full h2` and `.article-full h3` from the DOM structure except the h2 and h3 contained in
`.toc-excluded`

I tried

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".article--full :not(.toc-excluded) h2, .article--full :not(.toc-excluded) h3"
);
headings.forEach(hd => hd.classList.add("red"))
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='article--full'>
  <div>many divs in between</div>
  <div class='toc-excluded'>
    <div>many divs in between</div>
    <h2>h2</h2>
    <h3>h3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>many divs in between</div>
  <div class='manyotherdivs'><h2>h2</h2></div>
   <div class='manyotherdivs'><h3>h3</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve] You could have done that too

Comment: I don't know whether a CSS selector will be able to do this alone. It's just not designed for this kind of scenario. You may need to just get all h2/h3s and check their parent in code

Comment: Your current code snippet seems to be working. It's edited a few times, does this still accurately depict your scenario?

Comment: @3limin4t0r The current snippet selects the last two H* elements, I've understood the question so, that the first two h* elements should be excluded from the NodeList, i.e. everything but the first two H*s should appear red.

Comment: @Teemu i don't quite get it. it seems to be dependant of some divs in between . why are the .toc-excluded h3s are not excluded in here https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/eYJLPjP ?

Comment: The syntaxes `<selector><descendant combinator>:not` and `:not(<complex selector>)` are not supported in all browsers. In those browsers these syntaxes are supported, I suppose `.article--full :not(.toc-excluded h2, .toc-excluded h3)` would work.

Comment: @teemu it does not seem to work in my codepen. How could i select all h2s and h3s then remove the ones with .toc-excluded parents?

Comment: It looks like I can't create such a selector using Firefox (that doesn't mean it would be impossible). Maybe you should go with Liam's suggestion ..? (In my tests the descendant combinator selects all inspite of `:not`, and using a complex selector within `:not` causes a CSS error.)

Comment: @Teemu that's what i am trying now without success, removing nodes from the nodelist depending on the parent .

Comment: NodeList is read-only, convert it to an array and use that array instead of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the syntaxes of `:not` are not fully supported yet, hence it's better to rely on old good JS instead. As Liam suggested, you've to filter the elements you want to exclude out of the list, like this:

```js
const headings = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.article--full h2, .article--full h3')
  ).filter(el => !el.closest('.toc-excluded'));

headings.forEach(hd => hd.classList.add("red"));
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

h2,
h3 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="article--full">
  <div>many divs in between</div>
  <div class="toc-excluded">
    <div>many divs in between</div>
    <h2>h2</h2>
    <h3>h3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>many divs in between</div>
  <div class="manyotherdivs">
    <h2>h2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="manyotherdivs">
    <h3>h3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The returned NodeList must be converted to an array before filtering, since the list itself is read-only, and it doesn't support `filter` method. The header elements need their own CSS, otherwise the font color is inherited, and there wouldn't be any visual difference.

Comment: the divs should not be red as there are no headers

Comment: as a complement to Teemu reply , i have sorted myself once the nodelist converted to array as such https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/BajOGMq

Comment: @Matoeil The question was "_How can I exclude the h2 and h3 contained in `.toc-excluded`_", there were no other conditions. Please describe the wanted result more accurately, I can fix the answer correspondingly.

Comment: i have editd the question trying to be more precise